# How can I change the size of the second ax in ordinate?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Hello I have this code using Python :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)


a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = a 
ax1.plot(a,b)

x = 0.125
xx = 0
z = 0.9
zz = 0.32

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
#ax2.set_position(matplotlib.transforms.Bbox([[x, x], [z, zz]])) Here is the problem

c = np.array([4,5,6])
d = c

ax2.plot(c,d)

plt.show()
```

Actually the problem is in this line because without this line I get his :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir3bQ.png)

And what I would like is something like this at the right : (changing the scale of the ax2)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VgMO.png)

Do you have any ideas to do this ?

Thank you very much !

I precise I use Python3 not Python2.

Comment: It's not really clear what the desired output is, but clearly you cannot use `set_position` on a twin axes. Instead you may want to change the limits, e.g. `ax2.set_ylim(3, 16)`.

Comment: No because in my case I just want `ax2.set_ylim(4,16)`